# Azure MariaDB connection via private network

Tags: azure, networking, mariadb

In Azure I have:
- an "Azure Database for MariaDB server"
- a Linux virtual machine (+ a public IP for it).
- a virtual network (192.168.x.x)

The virtual network is assigned to both MariaDB and the virtual machine so, they should be able to communicate via this virtual/private network. Linux vm has an address in the private network.

In portal.azure.com, the configuration of MariaDB shows only its public fqdn internet name like: blabla.mariadb.database.azure.com and I cannot find its 192.168.x.x private address. Therefore, in the scripts on the linux server I use this blabla.mariadb.database.azure.com which, I assume, doesn't go via the private network but via the internet instead, which is not what I want (for speed and other reasons).

Does anyone know how to find the private IP address of the MariaDB SaaS in Azure so that I connect directly to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable Microsoft.SQL service endpoint on your virtual network and assign your mariadb to the same network. that way it would use internal network to talk to mariadb (you should continue using the same DNS name).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: (sorry, StackOverflow is peculiar and I sent the message unfinished) I checked and all is set up as indicated (also in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/concepts-data-access-security-vnet ) 
However, if I ping mariadb dns name from the vm in the virtual network, I get answer from same ip like when I ping it from my home computer. Need to find a way to check it is working. Will try the monitoring of packets in the private network.

Comment: its working, just look at the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview#key-benefits

Comment: Sorry, I need more than "it is working because so said the docs" :-)
However I got the proof by:
- cutting the access to MariaDB from Azure services (uncheck Allow access to Azure services) and using no firewall exceptions.
- removing the Microsoft.SQL service endpoint
In the moment I couldn't access MariaDB from the VM. 
Then, adding back the service endpoint it started to work, which means it is indeed using the virtual network and not the public interface.
Thank you.

Comment: you can, by the same token, argue that this is not working, its just pretending to be working. this makes no sense as you do not really know what all of those checkboxes unless, unless you trust microsoft they do what the do. and if you trust microsoft, you probably trust the docs as well

Comment: @NeluBidonelu I'm trying to validate this by myself too because I think it is important to make sure you're getting what you pay for. Something very strange I found is that resolving the DNS name of the database inside the VMs that consume it results in public IPs instead of private IPs.

How is it possible for them to route the packets interally if they are using a public IP? This is something I'll validate with Azure support tomorrow. This network is very confusing compared to AWS and you have to "trust them". With AWS you can validate everything.